# Displaying Validations using dataannotaion

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations

I am new to Entity Framework, I have created a EDM using Model first appraoch and applied validations using datannotations, everything is working fine but all the validations are displayed at one place but i would like to show validation error messages beside the respective field.

The code i written is as below

```
public partial class Hardware_services_repairs
{
public class hardwaremetadata
{
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage="Numbers and Special characters are not      allowed")]
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z]+$", ErrorMessage="Numbers and Special characters are not allowed")]
public string ContactName { get; set; }
//[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9+-]+$",ErrorMessage="Only numbers are allowed")]
public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
//[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^[0-9+-]+$", ErrorMessage = "Only numbers are allowed")]
public string MobileNumber { get; set; }
//[Required]
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9#: ]+$", ErrorMessage = "Special Characters are not allowed")]
public string Address { get; set; }
}
}
```

The output is as shown below

```
List of validation errors
Numbers and Special characters are not allowed
Numbers and Special characters are not allowed
Only numbers are allowed
Only numbers are allowed
Special Characters are not allowed
```

But i want every error message separtely beside the respective field, kindly let me the solution

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, the problem is in your View.

The parameter "excludePropertyErrors" of the method "ValidationSummary" must be set to "true":

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) { 
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
```

Then, for each field, you have to write something like this:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyName) 
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyName)
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to add @Html.validationSummary

Add an validationMessageFor to every field you want to validate and show the validation error

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CompanyName) 
</div>
<div>
    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CompanyName)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CompanyName)
</div>
```